# How to convert JSON objects with numeric keys to list in Android?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have this JSON response

```
{
    "episodes": {
        "1": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "2": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "3": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It's dynamically returned from server like "1", "2", "3" and those numbers are not constant and could be "1", "2" for another result.

```
    data class Episodes(
        val episodes: Map<List<String>, List<Episode>>) {

        data class Episode(
            @SerializedName("id")
            val id: String,
            @SerializedName("episode_num")
            val num: String,
            @SerializedName("title")
            val title: String,
            @SerializedName("container_extension")
            val extension: String,
            @SerializedName("info")
            val info: EpisodeInfo) {

            data class EpisodeInfo(
                @SerializedName("movie_image")
                val thumbnail: String,
                @SerializedName("cover_big")
                val cover: String,
                @SerializedName("rating")
                val rating: Double,
                @SerializedName("release_date")
                val releaseDate: String,
                @SerializedName("duration")
                val duration: String)
        }
    }
```

That's my DTO in Android. I tried to convert those objects to a list of strings. Tried a lot of solutions but without any success.

Update: I have tried to replace

```
val episodes: Map<List<String>, List<Episode>>
```

with

```
val episodes: Map<String, List<Episode>>
```

and no success.

I have tried to get the "1" object directly and removed the map and it worked so the issue is not related to the Episode or EpisodeInfo

Comment: `"episodes"` is not a `Map<List<String>, List<Episode>>`, it's a `Map<String, List<Episode>>`. "Tried a lot of solutions but without any success" - show what you tried.

Comment: I have tried it that way too and didn't work.

Comment: @dominicoder I think the issue could be the SerializedName? As we mapped it and the JSON response is without a name?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that comment. You should update your question and better explain what you have tried and what "didn't work" means.

Comment: See if this helps put your question together in a way that others can understand your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.